# Appfabric strange behavior

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I've got a windows service hosting a WCF service running on machine A.
It retrieves objects from machine B running Appfabric where the actual objects are stored.
Machine B has 2 regions, "Articles" and "TestArticles". The live application uses Articles and my test program uses TestArticles.

It has been running for six months without problems but now suddenly the live application starts returning null for some objects until the service is restarted and all objects are cached again. Then it runs for a few hours and null's are being returned again.
Eviction and TTL is not used so objects should stay in there forever.
The only things I can think of is that the Appfabric server's memory is almost full. Only 43MB of 12GB is free!

So what I would like to know is what happens when an Appfabric server's memory is full and I try to cache more objects in the TestArticles region. They succeed but does Appfabric throw out objects from Articles then?

Answer (score 1):

The [Eviction Troubleshooting page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921021%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) has this to say:

> A Windows Server AppFabric cache cluster uses eviction to control the
>   amount of memory that the Caching Service uses on a cache host.
>   Eviction occurs during two scenarios:
>
> The available physical memory on the server is critically low.
>
> The Caching Service's memory usage exceeds the high watermark for the cache host.

The [Expiration and Eviction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790981%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) page also says:

> To maintain the memory capacity available for cache on each cache
>   host, AppFabric supports least recently used (LRU) eviction.

So, when your server runs out of memory, you should see LRU eviction.

There is no way to set the eviction policy per-region, so you would be better off either using different servers for live and test: or, if that isn't an option, create two caches - one for live and one for test - and set the test cache to evict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I've put some performancecounters on it now to see how often objects are evicted. Do you know how I can update existing objects in the cache without appfabric creating a new version? This to keep memory usage as low as possible of course.

Comment: The [Put method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424971%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) is said to 'add or replace an object in the cache' but I would expect replace in this context to mean 'remove the old version and add the new version' rather than an in-place update.

Comment: Yes it says that but nonetheless the memory usage keeps increasing every time I call put on an existing object.

Comment: It will, until the old instances are garbage collected. There is an [`Invoke-GC` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) which initiates garbage collection but as this is a live site you would want to be cautious of that.